Issue with converting C pointers to numpy arrays in Python
I'm trying to utilize a C library using ctypes in Python. The C library provides a subroutine that returns two arrays via pointers: one for integer data and one for float data.
Here's a simplified example of my Python code:
import ctypes
import numpy as np

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./reader.so')  # Assicurati di sostituire con il percorso corretto della tua libreria

readdata = lib.readdata
readdata.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))]

data_ptr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)()
xyz_ptr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)()
readdata(ctypes.byref(data_ptr), ctypes.byref(xyz_ptr))

size = 17  # Dimensione dell'array
data = np.frombuffer((ctypes.c_int * size).from_address(ctypes.addressof(data_ptr.contents)), dtype=np.int32)
xyz = np.frombuffer((ctypes.c_float * size).from_address(ctypes.addressof(xyz_ptr.contents)), dtype=np.float32)

print("Dati integer:", data)
print("Dati float:", xyz)

libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
libc.free(data_ptr)

This is the code of the fortran module (reader.so):
subroutine readdata(data1, data2) bind(c, name='readdata')
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    
    integer(c_int), intent(out), dimension(:), allocatable :: data1
    real(c_float), intent(out), dimension(:), allocatable :: data2
    
    integer :: length, i
    
    length = 17  ! Esempio di dimensione, sostituire con la dimensione effettiva
    allocate(data1(length))
    allocate(data2(length))
    
    ! Assegna dati casuali all'array di interi data1
    do i = 1, length
        data1(i) = i * 10  ! Modifica questo assegnamento con la logica desiderata
    end do
    
    ! Assegna dati casuali all'array di float data2
    do i = 1, length
        data2(i) = real(i * 10, kind=4) 
    end do
    
end subroutine readdata

The problem is that I'm encountering an error when trying to convert the pointers into numpy arrays. I suspect that the pointers might be close to each other and may cause memory overlap issues.
I've tried rearranging the operations and manually deallocating memory, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Could someone help me understand how to properly solve this problem of converting C pointers to numpy arrays in Python?
Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Where are the "C pointers"?

This code is written in Python but uses ctypes to communicate with Fortran code

I don't have a Fortran compiler to test with, but initializing data_ptr and xyz_ptr with valid pointers to data (e.g. ctypes.c_int * 17(*range(17))) and running you np.frombuffer lines works.  Are your sure you Fortran code translates to a C prototype of readdata(int**, float**)?  What is the traceback of the error you get?

In the Fortran code the dummy arguments are (interoperable under F2018 rules) allocatable, but you don't show where the C address of any Fortran entity is involved.

It gives this error in Python: code=null. However, when I allocate one of these arrays, it works correctly but still returns code=null

If you think fortran allocatable arrays map simply onto C pointers you are going to be disappointed

Okey any similar solution?

I don't speak python so I can't be too specific, but I would keep my life simple with the general rule of "allocate the memory for objects that you want to use in the language that you want to use them in." So alloc in python - even if it needs two calls to the Fortran, one to return the size, one to populate the arrays, (Or do it all in Fortran)

I wanted a compact solution to avoid calling the Fortran subroutine twice (one for the size and one to populate the arrays)

Interoperability between C and Fortran beyond that provided by Fortran 2003 can involve a lot of effort.  Allocatable dummy arguments are definitely on the burdensome side of things.

Fortran allocatable array is not pointer to reference. It is a much more complex structure, see p. 18.5.3 "The CFI_cdesc_t structure type" (ISO/IEC 1539-1:2018) and/or header file "ISO_Fortran_binding.h" of your compiler.
Numpy (Python) allocated arrays are the simplest way:
import ctypes
import numpy as np

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./readdata2.so')  # Assicurati di sostituire con il percorso corretto della tua libreria

readdata2 = lib.readdata2

length = 17
data = np.empty(length, dtype=np.int32)
xyz = np.empty(length, dtype=np.float32)

data_ptr = data.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
xyz_ptr = xyz.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))

readdata2(data_ptr, xyz_ptr, ctypes.c_int(length))

print("Dati integer:", data)
print("Dati float:", xyz)

subroutine readdata2(data1, data2, length) bind(c, name='readdata2')
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    
    integer(c_int), intent(in), value :: length
    integer(c_int), intent(inout) :: data1(length)
    real(c_float), intent(inout) :: data2(length)
    
    integer :: i
    
    ! Assegna dati casuali all'array di interi data1
    do i = 1, length
        data1(i) = i * 10  ! Modifica questo assegnamento con la logica desiderata
    end do
    
    ! Assegna dati casuali all'array di float data2
    do i = 1, length
        data2(i) = real(i * 10, kind=4) 
    end do
    
end subroutine readdata2

$ gfortran -shared readdata2-240509.f90 -o readdata2.so && python readdata2-240509.py
Dati integer: [ 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170]
Dati float: [ 10.  20.  30.  40.  50.  60.  70.  80.  90. 100. 110. 120. 130. 140.
 150. 160. 170.]

